# Is mixing features of an animal and a human in art forbidden in Judaism (e.g., is making a sculpture or a drawing of a sphinx or similar forbidden)?

Tags: halacha, tanach, avodah-zarah, art

Recently, I've heard someone claim that mixing human and animal features when creating an artistic feature constitutes an element of idolatrous cultures and can bring harmful spirits or something similar. I am aware that in the Jewish traditions, such artistic pieces have been created for a variety of reasons like the [Birds' Head Haggadah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birds%27_Head_Haggadah), but I'm wondering what's written in the texts and whether such actions are actually not okay. Would one for instance, be allowed to create a sphinx or a different mix of human and animal features for an artistic piece intended for non-idolatrous reasons?